# How to set correctly set Local Host on a payload for a user outside subnet?

Tags: metasploit, kali-linux, meterpreter

I'm training with labs and metasploit and there's some payloads I can send to my target and exploit it(in my subnet). If I have to exploit a payload I sent to a target outside my network which options does I need to use in my payload configuration ? I've tried the usual option of `LHOST = 192.168.x.x` and did not work well.I'm using a payload with only two options of `LPORT and LHOST` and a handler with `LPORT and LHOST` with the same options in metasploit. (Using Kali Linux)

Any Ideas?

Comment: The `LHOST` host must be reachable by the target.

Comment: @Gumbo Can I do that with the internet? That's what I want to know

Comment: 192.168.0.0/16 is a private block. So unless your target is in the same network as you, you can’t use that address.

Comment: @Gumbo so, which address does I need to use to make this work? or is this impossible?

Comment: Well, your public, Internet facing address. And since you’re probably behind some router, you need to forward the `LPORT` as well.

Comment: @Gumbo oh, and I need to ensure that my IP don't changes....oh well..can you post the answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Btw, i tried and did not work, do you know if I need to add a route or something inside metasploit to make it work? i've already did port fwd @Gumbo

Comment: You need to [configure your *Internet* router to forward the port to your machine](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/).

Comment: @Gumbo I'll test later and give you the feedback, thanks for you support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mentioned IP address 192.168.x.x is from the [private network block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) 192.168.0.0/16. So unless your target is in the same network as you, you can’t use that address.

You need to provide an address that is reachable by the target like your public, Internet facing address. And since you’re probably behind some router, you also need to forward the `LPORT` on your router to your local machine.